# Parsing XML File with JAXB based on attribute values

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have a Maven and Spring based Java web application.

I have a **config.xml** file in src/main/resources.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sourceConfigs>
    <areas>
        <area name="Defects">
            <fileHeaders>ID,Issue Key,Fields
            </fileHeaders>
        </area>
        <area name="Organization">
            <fileHeaders>ID,Org Key,Fields
            </fileHeaders>
        </area>
    </areas>
    <sourceTypes>
        <source name="source1">
            <adapterObject>source1Adapter</adapterObject>
            <resultObject>JsonObject</resultObject>
        </source>
        <source name="source2">
            <adapterObject>source2Adapter</adapterObject>
            <resultObject>sourceObject</resultObject>
        </source>
    </sourceTypes>
</sourceConfigs>
```

I want to parse the above XML to Java object based on the attributes.

I have created two classes.

**Area.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="area")
public class Area {
        String name;
    String fileHeaders;

    @XmlAttribute
    //get Name
    //set Name

    @XmlElement
    //get fileHeaders
    //set FileHeaders
}
```

**Source.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="source")
public class Source {
        String name;
    String adapterObject;
    String resultObject;

    @XmlAttribute
    //get Name
    //set Name

    @XmlElement
    //get adapterObject
    //set adapterObject

    @XmlElement
    //get resultObject
    //set resultObject
}
```

I want to parse the XML based on the attribute value.
 ie; if the attribute value of area is `Defects`, the parsed object should have the values based on that, else if its `Organization`, then the values based on that and object type to **Area** object. Similarly for **Source** type also.

How can I do that?

When it was only a simple XML file like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sourceConfig area="Defects">
    <adapterObject>jAdapter</adapterObject>
    <resultObject>jsonObject</resultObject>
</sourceConfig>
```

My POJO was based on that and the code I used to parse is

```
public SourceConfig getConfigObject() throws JAXBException, IOException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SourceConfig.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("config.xml");
        File file=resource.getFile();

        SourceConfig sourceConfig = (SourceConfig) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        return sourceConfig;
    }
```

But for this complex I don't know how to parse based on attribute values, and also multiple list of data.

How to parse based on the attribute values?
I have created two POJOs for parsing different kind. If it's a single class also it's fine.

**UPDATE 1**

My expected output.

When I pass the value `"Defects"` when unmarshalling the Area object, The values should be

```
name= Defects
fileHeaders=ID,Issue Key,Fields
```

And If I pass `"Organization"`, The area object values should be based on that. Similarly when unmarshalling source.

Now I am getting as List of Areas and List of SourceTypes, then I take the corresponding object by checking the value.

May be is there any way to parse only selected one based on attribute value instead of getting list and then checking value and returning the object?

Comment: if the attribute value of area is Defects, the parsed object should have the values based on that, else if its Organization, then the values based on that and object type to Area object.  can u explain how u want .. above stmt is not clear to me..sample output how u want

Comment: @Naren Please see my **UPDATE 1**

Comment: that is the way JAXB unmarshalling process done.. i think we cant get output based on our input..That generally unmarshalls all the objects

Comment: Ok. What I am doing now is get list of objects. Creat a map with String as key and value as object. The put all attribute name as key and object as value. Then get the corresponding object.

Comment: yeah.. that is what we have to do get ur functionality..

Comment: Are you looking for something like the following:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html